# Attaching relationship on user create (Laravel 5.4)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I got a problem, where I get a `NULL` value when I try to attach a school_id on a user creation. School has a hasMany relationship to users.

This is my UserController store function:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user->school_id = $request->school_id;

    $user = User::create($request->all());

    $user->attachRole(Role::where('id', $request->role)->first());

    return redirect()->route('user.index');
}
```

View:

```
 <div class="form-group">
     <select class="form-control" name="school_id" required>
        <option disabled selected>Vælg skole</option>
             @foreach ($schools as $school)
                 <option value="{{ $school->id }}">{{ $school->name }}</option>
             @endforeach
     </select>
 </div>
```

Comment: You're assigning `$user->school_id`, then rewriting everything when you assign `$user` right below that. Which should probably throw an error anyway because `$user` isn't defined when you first try to use it.

Comment: @aynber Placing $user->school_id under $user = User::create($request->all()); does not work either?

Comment: Not necessarily relevant to your question but `Role::where('id', $request->role)->first()` can be changed to `Role::find($request->role)`

Comment: You need to save the user model as well after you assign it, if you want to keep the setting. It does not auto-save.

Comment: Thanks! I called $user->save(); and it worked! :D